# Power BI Bookmarks Conflicts With Other Bookmarks

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have 4 bookmarks; 1. All Years, 2. YTD, 3. QTD and 4. MTD. However, when I click 1 & 2, the other 3 and 4 bookmarks would change. Is there any way to disable their connections?

I tried to arrange my visuals in selection pane, but I noticed that the bookmark is following the order ins election pane.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.